# Property Manager using Qt5

Tags: qt

I am aware that Qt has a property browser extension called `QPropertyBrowser`. But I would like to make my own.

My question is, for the browser in QtCreator (see image below), how is it made?

- Do they use a `QTreeWidget` with a seperate `QTreeView` and linked
  model per category?
- Do they use a single model and `QTreeView` and somehow create a delegate for alternating row colors for different categories? I assume it's this based off the single Property/Value header up the top (that controls the width of all columns together).

I know there is the 'All roads lead to Rome' response, but I'd like to know what the best way is, not just any way (this assumes the way they did it is the best way).

[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Qt Creator source yourself?

Comment: @MrEricSir it will probably take longer to just find it in the source and make anything of it than to just write it from scratch.

Comment: You should check the code here : https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtpropertybrowser